# Polymer 2.0: where should I place business logic?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, polymer-2.x

I'm starting with Polymer, 2.0, and I have a design question that I cannot find an answer to, and I hope you can help me.

The point is that I'm working on a Task Manager system that consumes an external api (laravel in this case) to start/stop a task, edit or create a new one, etc.

What I'm not able to find is the best approach to handle the business specific logic, because as far as I know the Polymer Elements should be reusable and including the api calls and other funtionality into the Polymer Element doesn't seem to be the best solution, although it's the easiest.

I have several alternatives in mind:

- Manage everything using custom events from a top level JS class that make the api calls and update the Polymer Elements.
- Use mixins to extend from Polymer Element and a custom Task class containing the needed methods/logic.
- pass to the Polymer Element a Task object and save it as a property and call the method through it.

Could anybody tell me which is the best approach? Although I'm sure that is not going to be any of the three I said :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

there are several approches

**1) use a tag to read and modify data (live db)**

```
// firebase example
<firebase-query
    id="query"
    app-name="notes"
    path="/notes/[[uid]]"
    data="{{data}}">
</firebase-query>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}" as="note">
  <sticky-note note-data="{{note}}"></sticky-note>
</template>
```

Using this you can access {{data}} and modify it. So if you delete a note it will be automatically deleted on the server and on every other connected client (a feature you get with a live db like firebase)
=> see https://www.webcomponents.org/element/firebase/polymerfire/firebase-query

*As far as I can tell you are going to use php to create an api for the data right? so a live db is out of the question. So*

**2) use a tag to read (and modify) data**

Probably the best way would be to create a data-provider for stuff you need
e.g.

```
<data-notes notes="{{notes}}"></notes>
<data-comments comments="{{comments}}" for="[[currentNote]]"></notes>
```

So you can still easily access {{notes}} and {{comments}}.

How you handle updates depends on your use case then. You could for example use changeEvents in the data handler to dynamically do api updates via fetch or iron-ajax.

Or you could do "normal" post requests with a form and trigger the data provider to fetch new data.

I personally like to totally encapsulate my data so I do not have to think about it. E.g. how and where the data comes from I don't care :p

Examples for data sources:

- static: json inside the component itself
  => https://github.com/Polymer/shop/blob/2.0-preview/src/shop-category-data.html
- sub element: for example use iron-ajax to actually load the data from a json api
- fetch: use fetch to load data, process it and store it to be used
- browser storage: use html5 localStorage or indexedDB (for temporary data maybe?) => https://github.com/Polymer/shop/blob/2.0-preview/src/shop-cart-data.html
- ...

**3) use something like Redux (for lots of dynamic data)**

But keep in mind that it adds an "extra" layer you have to think about.

When should I use Redux?

> In general, use Redux when you have reasonable amounts of data
>   changing over time, you need a single source of truth, and you find
>   that approaches like keeping everything in a top-level React
>   component's state are no longer sufficient.

more => http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/General.html#general-when-to-use

a simple example with Polymer:
https://tur-nr.github.io/polymer-redux/